# Least Recently Used Cache without using LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, lru

Trying to do Least Recently Used Cache is expected to keep all items that have been used the most recent and discard the ones that haven’t been used in the longest amount of time as it becomes full. The get() method should return null in cases where it does not return an Object. Moreover, assume getMaxSize() will return the maximum number of items that can be
in the cache. We aren’t worrying about memory footprint or anything like that - just the number of items.

I know it is so much easier with LinkedHashMap but You can't use the LinkedHashMap here.

So far I have done this, any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
  class Entry {
    int value;
    int key;
    Entry left;
    Entry right;
}
public class LRUCache {

    HashMap<Integer, Entry> hashmap;
    Entry start, end;
    int LRU_SIZE = 4; // Here i am setting 4 to test the LRU cache
                        // implementation, it can make be dynamic
    public LRUCache() {
        hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, Entry>();
    }

    public int getEntry(int key) {
        if (hashmap.containsKey(key)) // Key Already Exist, just update the
        {
            Entry entry = hashmap.get(key);
            removeNode(entry);
            addAtTop(entry);
            return entry.value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void putEntry(int key, int value) {
        if (hashmap.containsKey(key)) // Key Already Exist, just update the value and move it to top
        {
            Entry entry = hashmap.get(key);
            entry.value = value;
            removeNode(entry);
            addAtTop(entry);
        } else {
            Entry newnode = new Entry();
            newnode.left = null;
            newnode.right = null;
            newnode.value = value;
            newnode.key = key;
            if (hashmap.size() > LRU_SIZE) // We have reached maxium size so need to make room for new element.
            {
                hashmap.remove(end.key);
                removeNode(end);                
                addAtTop(newnode);

            } else {
                addAtTop(newnode);
            }

            hashmap.put(key, newnode);
        }
    }
    public void addAtTop(Entry node) {
        node.right = start;
        node.left = null;
        if (start != null)
            start.left = node;
        start = node;
        if (end == null)
            end = start;
    }

    public void removeNode(Entry node) {

        if (node.left != null) {
            node.left.right = node.right;
        } else {
            start = node.right;
        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            node.right.left = node.left;
        } else {
            end = node.left;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        LRUCache lrucache = new LRUCache();
        lrucache.putEntry(1, 1);
        lrucache.putEntry(10, 15);
        lrucache.putEntry(15, 10);
        lrucache.putEntry(10, 16);
        lrucache.putEntry(12, 15);
        lrucache.putEntry(18, 10);
        lrucache.putEntry(13, 16);

        System.out.println(lrucache.getEntry(1));
        System.out.println(lrucache.getEntry(10));
        System.out.println(lrucache.getEntry(15));

}
```

Comment: Hi - can you explain why you can't use `LinkedHashMap` here?

Comment: Combination of `doubly linked list` and `hashtable` will do. Search `LRU` via google for details. For Java the 2 structures could be: `LinkedList` and `HashMap`. This will result in `O(1)` for `loop up` / `add` / `delete` / `update`.

Comment: @CPerkins: The reason is, I am trying to improve my technical skills and see if I can do without LinkedHashMap.

Comment: This question would be better asked on the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.